# Bootstrap 4 tabs work when there's 2 of them, but break with 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having an issue getting bootstrap4 tabs to work properly, they work fine with 2 tabs, with the following code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="registration-picker-acc-select" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link login-link active" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#form-login">
                    Login
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link register-link" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#form-register">
                    Register
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="form-login" class="tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel">
                {include file="inc/shared/my-account/login-form.html"}
            </div>
            <div id="form-register" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel">
                {include file="inc/shared/register/form.html"}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this breaks:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="cart-picker-acc-select" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link login-link active" id="form-login-top" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#form-login">
                    Login
                </a>
            </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link register-link" id="form-register-top" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#form-register">
                        Register
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link continue-without-register-link" id="form-guest-top" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#form-guest">
                        Continue without an account
                    </a>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="form-login" class="tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="form-login-top">
                {include file="inc/shared/my-account/login-form.html"}
            </div>
                <div id="form-register" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="form-register-top">
                    {include file="inc/shared/register/form.html"}
                </div>
                <div id="form-guest" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="form-guest-top">
                    {include file="inc/shared/cart/step2/guest/form.html"}
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the following:
Clicking on the first 2 tabs works fine, they switch as expected, but the third tab when it is nav is clicked starts to break the rest.

- the `fade` classes disappear from the panels
- transitions break
- third panel will randomly stay visible after switching to another one

I have ran the page through the w3 validator to check for possible id conflicts, but it parsed through just fine with 0 messages

I'd like to also note that the parts that show up in the tabs have their own tabs as well

Answer (score 1):

The following code is fine, there was a bug in bootstrap 4.0.0-beta1, but upgrading to bootstrap 4.0.0-beta2 solves the issue.